# How to return an ID with an '<input type='text' string from Java using JSON and AJAX to HTML

Tags: java, html, json, ajax

I have some Award images with dates under them that I am retrieving using Java and then passing back to HTML with JSON and AJAX to display. Each Award has a unique ID. When I change a date under one of the Award images I want to use the Award image ID to update the correct date.

How do I capture the correct Award ID to update the date for?

Also, the AJAX $('#awardDate').on('change', function() is not being triggered (i.e., I do not see the alert when I change a date. I have used Inspect in Chrome and no errors are shown.

The Java that extracts the images is in a 'for' loop (if this code fragment is not enough then I can add all the code):

The WebServlet opens with:

```
public class GetYMAwardsView extends HttpServlet implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String ymID = null;

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

The loop contains:

```
            awardType2 = youthMemberAward.getAwAwardType();
            //Youth encrypted member ID is stored in session storage - ssYMID
            //The encrypted Award ID is: encoded_award_ID
            //Selecting the picture will display the requirements for the Award
            //Updating the date under the Award will be saved to the database for that Award
            json = "<h3>" + awardType2 + "</h3>";
            json = json + "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-1'><a href='CubAwardOverview.html?id=" + encoded_award_ID +
                    "'><img src=" +
                    image + " height='90' width='90' style='border-style: none' alt='award image' /></a>" +
                    "<div class='caption'> <p>" + 
                    "<input type='text' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + newstring + "' style='width: 90px;'/>" +
                    "</p> </div></div>";
            i++; col++;
```

And then passed back with:

```
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
```

The HTML is:

```
    <form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="selectAward">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- div class="col-xs-12"> -->
                <div class="form-select">
                    <!-- Place for Award image -->
                    <div class="input-group" id="img-container2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--</div>-->
        </div>
    </form>
```

Once all the images are displayed, with the date under them, I try to catch the change in a date with AJAX. The AJAX I am using to catch the change of 'awardDate' is:

```
$('#awardDate').on('change', function() {
    alert($("#awardDate").val());
    var dataToBeSent  = {
            ssYMID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssYMID'),
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UpdateAwardedDateView",
        cache: false,
        data: $(awardDate).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('Awarded date success.');
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#awardDate").focus();
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('An error occured applying the awarded date.');
        }
    }).done(function(responseJson) {
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text('Awarded date completed.');
    });
});
```

In this AJAX call I want to pass the Youth Member's ID (ssYMID), Award ID and new date to the WebServlet"UpdateAwardedDateView".

Comment: Could you possibly explain how the mechanism of update between Front-end and Back-end work in your code? As far as I see you trigger POST request when an image is changed. It is bit unclear how it corresponds to the fact that you pull and push images from Java code.
Plus, please try your code out in Chrome Incognito mode, it may be possible that Chrome cached your files and when you update the page, they are not reloaded, so alert is not triggered.

Comment: I have updated the post and I hope this explains what you want. I am not a programmer by trade and and am doing this for free learning as I go. So please let me know specifically what you want. I have used Chrome Incognito mode and no errors are displayed.

Comment: Can you post example of your code in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? At the moment, there is still not enough information. It may be because you have several IDs in HTML with the same name, it may be some other reason.

Comment: I have posted it at https://jsfiddle.net/bes53yw0/ The site wants HTML (OK) and JS. I am using JAVA and AJAX so I have placed the JAVA and AJAX in the same space. I hope this is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
"<input type='text' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + newstring + "' style='width: 90px;'/>" +
```

With:

```
json = json + "<p>";
json = json + "<input class='form-control mr-sm-2' type='date' name='awardDate' id='awardDate' value='" + youthMemberAward.getCaAwardedDate() + "' onchange='myFunction(this.value, " + youthMemberAward.getAwId() + ")' style='width: 160px;'/>";
json = json + "</p>";
```